# Can't run fixtures because of missing apostrophes Doctrine ? (Symfony 2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When i try to create my fixtures i'm 100% sure that they are correct but they are giving me errors when trying to load them about the table names.

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM group':
```

Which of course can't be loaded because it is missing the apostrophes (`)

anybody got an idea why this is happening?

Comment: are you using Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture?

Comment: Yes i am: class LoadGroupData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface

Comment: nice, could you post one of your fixtures?, I've never see this before

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/tyeazET8

Comment: it seems ok... could you drop your schema in mysql, create it again and try to load the fixtures?

Comment: Ye, i tried that, i noticed it was on a latin scheme so i changed it to an utf8_general_ci scheme now but it is still showing the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `Table` annotation with the escaped table name on the `Group` entity:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table("`group`")
 */
class Group {
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked, but since when is this needed then? because from just looking at http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html you can see that it is actually not used in there and it works in the example.

Comment: It's needed because `group` is a reserved word in most RDBMSes.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks for that. It worked and now i know why i was wrong :) thank you very much.